# Windows Media Player not compatible with .NET 6?

Tags: .net-6.0

So I'm redoing a project that was done in .NET Framework 4.7.2. When I started the new project I didn't think about what I should choose so I chose .NET 6, now I'm basically done with the app just have to add the wmp but now it shows it's incompatible. I've tried adding it as a reference and then adding it in the toolbox, just adding it in the toolbox but nothing works. I could just switch to Framework 4.7.2 but then I get error because I used the `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly`.

Is there a trick to make it work or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't. In particular, can you share a [Minimal piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can help us reproduce the issue? Screenshots of the UI not working (eg, "adding in the toolbox but nothing works") or a copy paste of the errors ("now it shows it's incompatible") will also help us to debug, identify and resolve the issues.

Comment: Change the project target version to be 4.7.2 and it should work.

Comment: No support for ActiveX controls in .NETCore, the basic plumbing (like aximp.exe) is missing.  Using WMP only for playback is still possible, add the COM reference, but you can't get the visible representation.  And therefore not the design-time support either.